# How do I find the first occurrence of a regex in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  Is there a quicker way to find the string index of the first occurrence of a regex? I have this

```
        first_occurrence = s.enum_for(:scan, regex).map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }.first
```

but it seems inefficient as I'm gathering all positions and then just taking the first one.

Comment: Why not use `s =~ /regex/`?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need an example input and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
first_occurrence = s =~ /regex/
```

If the result is not `nil`, it contains the index of the first match. See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/Zuzf6V).

See [Ruby 2.4 documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-3D-7E+operator):

> `=~` is Ruby's basic pattern-matching operator. ... *If a match is found, the operator returns index of first match in string, otherwise it returns `nil`*.

Comment: Not just `s =~ regex`? Why `\\`?

Comment: That is a typo.

Answer (score 4):

The one I like even more is accessing the found match or `nil` via the brackets expression:

```rb
"trololol"[/lo/]
=> "lo"

"trololol"[/rofl/]
=> nil
```

The feature is documented here in the [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)